# Is 'centimetres' optional in these sentences?

Tags: word-choice

Is "centimetres" optional in these examples? In BrE.

> 1.*I am 1.75 one metre seventy-five centimetres.*
> 2.*I am a hundred and seventy-five centimetres.*
> 3.*I am a hundred and seventy-five centimetres tall.*
> 4.*I am a hundred and seventy.*

Comment: (2) will probably be understood as meaning how tall you are, (3) definitely will, although most people in the UK still use feet and inches to talk about personal height, and might look around for a conversion table, and (4) normally means you are 170 years old. (1) doesn't make sense with those figures.

Answer (score 1):

> I am 1.75 one metre seventy-five centimetres.

I would drop the 1.75 and add tall at the end unless it is a response to a specific request about my height.

> I am one metre seventy five tall
> What is your height? I am one metre seventy five

> I am a hundred and seventy-five centimetres.

That is not correct

> I am a hundred and seventy-five centimetres tall.

That is OK but not as good as the first one

> I am a hundred and seventy.

That would be the way you would state your age although I agree that 170 years old is implausible.

You asked about British English and perhaps worth noting that many people would give their height in feet and inches still. The last time I gave mine in metric I was asked if I was from the military or a scientist.

Comment: I'd be happy with dropping the word "tall", if the context was clear.  I'd also allown dropping "cm" if "m" has already been mentioned.  "How tall are you?--One metre seventy five."

Comment: Yes, we can happily say "I am six foot three" (yes, 'foot').